# Why is "False == False != True" True in Python but false in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, conditional-statements

My trainee just reached out to me and asked why `False == False != True` evaluates to
`True` in Python, but `false` in JavaScript.

I think that statement is `false` / `False`, no matter how you solve it, it spits out `False` in my head.

Heres the breakdown:

```
given: 
False == False != True

#Case 1:
False == False => True
True != True => False

#Case 2:
False != True => True
False == True => False
```

[image]

Am I missing something obvious? I tried JS with `!= and ===` but since the type is the same, it keeps the same ouput.

Comment: JS: `false == false` -> `true` -> `true != true` -> `false`

Comment: `False` and `True` are going to be `undefined` in JavaScript, the constants are `false` and `true`

Comment: What is the *associativity* and *precedence* of these operators in the languages? Are you sure they are the same? In short, you need to know if `False == False != True` is the same as `(False == False) != True` or `False == (False != True)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in python it's actually `False == False and False != True` because python chains boolean operations

Comment: Lesson for today: Different languages have different rules, and does things in different ways. The comparison behaves one way in Python (see @Konrad) and a different way in JS. You can't really do a direct comparison between the languages here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python, you have [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)
This is usually intuitive for cases like `a < b < c`, but in that case, it gives that pretty unintuitive result. You need to parse

```py
False == False != True
```

as

```py
(False == False) and (False != True)
```

which then evaluates to `True`

Comment: What is `False == False != True` actually doing? `(False==False) != True` or `False == (False!=True)`

Comment: Is there actually a use-case why Python uses chained comparisons?

Comment: What do you mean? It is parsed by Python as `(False == False) and (False != True)` if that's your question @TomMcLean?

Comment: @SLNM so you can say something like `if x < y < z` instead of `if ((x < y) && (y < z))`

Comment: @SLNM Yes, usually it's to make sure that a variable is between 2 numbers, for instance: `if 10 < x < 20:` is better than `if (10<x) and (x<20)`

Comment: @SLNM Remember math where you can have something like `0 < a < 10`? Few languages implement this semantics, but Python does by this kind of chaining and it's well-defined in Python.

Comment: Oh okay, now the world makes sense again. Thank you very much @Someprogrammerdude and of course also Florent_Monin

Comment: @FlorentMonin Ahh I get what its doing now with the comment by jared smith. Good answer

Comment: @TomMcLean In the code like [this](https://onecompiler.com/python/3yyse4c36) you can see that comparison is made between x and y and then between y and z